# Access private properties in a class hierarchy from a common base function

Tags: php, polymorphism

I want to define a method once in a base class and call it in successive constructors in a class hierarchy.  Each time is it called I want it to operate on the properties of the class from which it is called.

For example, A is the base class and the method is defined here.  B inherits from A, and C inherits from B.

When I instantiate the concrete class C the constructor will call the base class method, and I want it to operate on the properties of C.  (This will be a private array which I will populate when I initialise it).

The constructor of C then calls `parent::__construct`.  When the B constructor calls the base class method, the method should operate on the properties of B.  Before the B constructor is complete it will call `parent::_construct`, and the A constructor will operate on the properties of A.

I was looking into LSB, but it won't work correctly because `parent::__construct` is a forwarding call.  I tried using the result of `get_parent_class()` in place of `parent::`, but my calls to `static::propertyName` error out because `propertyName` is not a constant.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Here's a code example.  The code below outputs "P Q P Q P Q".  I want it to output "P Q R S T U".

```
class A {
    private $property = array('P','Q');

    function __construct() {
        $this->myMethod();
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        foreach ($this->property as $value) {
            echo $value . " ";
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private $property = array('R','S');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    private $property = array('T','U');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }
}

$c = new C();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. In case of private the variable is not available to method and in case of public/protected its overwritten.

You can get your desired result by passing

```
$this->property
```

in each myMethod call like this -

```
$this->myMethod($this->property)
```

and changing your myMethod definition accordingly.

Comment: Hey kewlashu, nice one.  You make it seem obvious in hindsight!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this is your example:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function someMethod($arg) {
        $someProperty = $arg;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class C extends B {

    private $someProperty;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Everything works as you would expect. There is only one problem; class A has no property `someProperty`. If you want to use it in class A, you have to define it there. If you want to use it in subclasses, you have to make it `protected`. Your class A has therefore to look like this:

```
class A {

    protected $someProperty;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function someMethod($arg) {
        $this->someProperty = $arg;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in class B and C, and class A can use the property with `someMethod`:

```
$instance = new C();
$instance->someMethod("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your example has `$property` defined as `private` and you never override `myMethod`, when an object of type `C` or `B` is instantiated, it runs class `A`'s constructor, which calls `myMethod()` from class `A` where the value of `$property` is `array('P', 'Q');`.

If you want it to print 'P Q R S T U' you'll have to override `myMethod()` and call it from each individual class' `__construct()` method, OR declare `$property` to be `protected` so that the child classes can overwrite its value.

Something like this:

```
class A {
    private $property = array('P','Q');

    function __construct() {
        $this->myMethod();
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        foreach ($this->property as $value) {
            echo $value . " ";
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private $property = array('R','S');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        foreach ($this->property as $value) {
            echo $value . " ";
        }
    }
}

class C extends B {
    private $property = array('T','U');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        foreach ($this->property as $value) {
            echo $value . " ";
        }
    }
}

$c = new C();
```

OR THIS:

```
class A {
    protected $property = array('P','Q');

    function __construct() {
        $this->myMethod();
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        foreach ($this->property as $value) {
            echo $value . " ";
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $property = array('R','S');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    protected $property = array('T','U');

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->myMethod();
    }
}

$c = new C();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I'm not keen to repeat the method, as per your first example.  As for the second example, I tried this, but C::property overwrites A and B, so I just end up with T U T U T U.

Answer (score 0):

`proptery` cannot be overloaded in child classes.  Once you have a `C`, it does not have the private properties of `A` anymore.  It has no way to access them (outside of reflection).  The only way you would be able to do this would be to pass the properties to `someMethod` in a chain, but this requires access to the desired property.

Using `protected` would not work either because then the children would just override the parent property.

The solution to this is not have have `C` *be* an a (is-a) but have `C` have the properties of an `A` (has-a .. composition).  This would require some rework of your hierarchy, though, and your calls would have to be more explicit.  Something like

```
class C {
   private $b;
   private $properties = array('T', 'U');
   public function __construct(B $b) {
      $this->b = $b;
   }
   public function someMethod() {
      $this->b->someMethod($properties);
   }
}
class B {
   private $properties = array('R', 'S');
   private $a;
   public function __construct(A $a) {
      $this->a = $a;
   }
   public function someMethod($properties) {
      $this->a->someMethod(array_merge($this->properties, $properties));
   }
}
class A {
   private $properties = array('P', 'Q');
   public function someMethod($properties) {
      //your implementation plus an array_merge
   }
}
```

This obviously increases verbosity in your definitions, which is bad.  You may want to reconsider why you have to do some things the way you are doing them.  You may be able to get around this with `trait`s (assuming you have PHP 5.4)